# Get "E484: Can't open file /tmp/foo/a" when using system("wget") in Vim

Tags: vim, wget, tmp

I have a small function that throws an error. This is the function:

```
function! GetPHPInfo(function_name)
  let page = system("wget -q -O - 'php.net/" . a:function_name)
  " let page = system("wget -q -O - 'google.com'")
  return page
endfunction
```

When I use wget from php.info, I get this error:

```
E484: Can't open file /tmp/vRXHL5q/7
```

But not when I use wget from google.com. I assume it's because google is a smaller page than php.net, and therefore can be written. How do I change the allowed size for tmp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your conclusion is wrong; there's no limit on the size of the temp file. Rather, I think this is an escaping issue. Because of special characters in the passed function name, the command line is invalid, that causes the command to fail, and therefore Vim cannot capture its output. Here's a demo that creates the same error (on Windows):

```
:echo system('echo "fo"o"')
```

#### Solution

You need to use `shellescape()`, at least for the function name that can contain special characters:

```
let page = system("wget -q -O - " . shellescape('php.net/' . a:function_name))
```

At the very least, you need to properly close the single quote:

```
let page = system("wget -q -O - 'php.net/" . a:function_name . "'")
```

Depending on how lenient `wget` is, additional URL-escaping may be required, too. (There's no built-in function for that.)

Comment: You're right! The unclosed single quote was the problem. The error message really led me astray. Another day in the life as a programmer. :) Thanks!